# Internet connection for iPad in India

Tags: india, cellphones, internet

Will my AT&T iPad from the USA work in India, or will I need a WiFi hot-spot to get an Internet connection?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if you will be able to buy a valid SIM card?

Answer (score 2):

I never tried but I think USA AT&T in India if work will work in roaming.

This is not about the connection for iPad. This is about overseas communications.

I think you have 2 options.

First one is use free Wi-fi or  is buy a new sim card for you ipad from a Indian company.